Next.js How to load SG file at CSR page
What I want to do
to load the SG page generated at build time in the CSR page.
app/
  SG/[id]/product/page.tsx
  CSR/page.tsx

(Next version is 14)
The HTML output file of the CSR is assumed to be as follows
  <div data-id="product1">
   // SG content
  </div>

This is similar to a CSR application implemented in regular React:
  <div id="root" data-id="product1"></div>
  <script src="..."></script>

In short, I want to replace the components under the div that were dynamically running in CSR with HTML statically built by Next.js.
I assume we need to implement a client js that switches the static HTML depending on the data attribute set in the div tag, how can we accomplish this?

Finally, we were able to display something CSR-like by displaying Next.js static HTML over Iframe (Note that it is assumed that it is of the same origin).
parent HTML:
<div id="target" data-id="product1"></div>
<script "src="/js/loadIframe.js></script>



js for calling iframe:
(function () {
  
  const embedTarget = document.getElementById('target');
  if(!embedTarget) {
    throw new Error('Not found target element');
  }
  const productId = embedTarget.getAttribute('data-id');
  if(!productId) {
    throw new Error('Not specified product ID');
  }

  const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  const iframeSrc = `/assets/products/${productId}.html`
  iframe.id = 'iframeId';
  iframe.src = iframeSrc;
  iframe.style.width = '100%';
  iframe.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  iframe.scrolling = 'no';

  iframe.onload = function () {
    iframe.contentWindow.postMessage({
      type: 'MESSAGE_FROM_PARENT_HTML',
      data: { productId },
    });
  };
  embedTarget.appendChild(iframe);

})();

Next.js(Client Component Root):
'use client';

import { ReactNode, useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';


interface MessageDataProps {
  productId: string;
}

interface OwnProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

export function ClientComponent({ children }: OwnProps) {
  const [messageData, setMessageData] = useState<MessageDataProps>();


  const receiveMessage = useCallback(
    (event: MessageEvent<{ type: string; data: HTMLPartsDataProps }>) => {
      const response = event.data;
      if (response.type === 'MESSAGE_FROM_PARENT_HTML') {
        setMessageData(response.data);
      }
    },
    []
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window === 'object') {
      window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage);
    }
    return () => window.removeEventListener('message', receiveMessage);
  }, [messageData]);

  if (messageData) {
    return (
      <div
        ref={ref}
        data-id={messageData.productId}
      >{children}
      </div>
    );
  }

}

